# Django - URL not found using generic views

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am writing a basic Events app which contains of two modules(apps) so far : users and events.

I am using Django 2.1 with Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04

So far, I've been able to handle users, but on events, I can't use Update, Detail and Delete generic views. All of them return 404.

My views.py:

```
class EventListView(ListView):

    model = EventModel
    template_name = 'event_list.html'
    queryset = EventModel.objects.order_by('start_date_time')


class EventUpdateView(UpdateView):

    model = EventModel
    fields = ['event_type','start_date_time'
              ]
    template_name = 'event_update.html'


class EventDeleteView(DeleteView):

    model = EventModel
    template_name = 'event_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('event_list')


class EventDetailView(DetailView):

    model = EventModel
    template_name = 'event_detail.html'
```

My urls.py (in project folder):

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', include('pages.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('users/', include('users.urls')),
path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
path('events/', include('events.urls')),
]
```

My urls.py (in events app):

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.EventListView.as_view(), name='event_list'),
path('<int:id>', views.EventDetailView.as_view(), name='event_detail'),
path('<int:id>/edit/', views.EventUpdateView.as_view(), name='event_update'),
path('<int:id>/delete/', views.EventDeleteView.as_view(), name='event_delete'),
]
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been searching the whole day and still have no idea how this might be wrong.
Note that the first line works (EventListView) but the other lines don't. By the way, I am using the book Django for Beginners. Most of the code here is identical to the code in the book.

**Update**

I don't use namespace in this application, the rest of urls.py is only some basic imports :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
```

The urls.py for the Project is like above, except it has include and admin as well.

The examples of URLs giving 404 error:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/events/1/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/events/1/edit/
```

PS I thought edit and delete give me 404, but actually the error is :

> ImproperlyConfigured at /events/1/edit/
>   EventUpdateView is missing a QuerySet. Define EventUpdateView.model, EventUpdateView.queryset, or override EventUpdateView.get_queryset().)

Comment: Did you define a `app_namespace`? Please post the *full* `urls.py` files, not the "limited" version.

Comment: How are you trying to use them? Please add examples of URLs giving you 404. Are you sure you are trying to make appropriate `POST` or `DELETE` and so on requests? not `GET`.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Using my browser, I am trying to access them. I haven't implemented any POST or GET explicitly. I am using generic views like above.

Comment: Well, at least it's not supposed to be `models = EventModel` it's `model` property. Not `model>>S<<`.

Comment: @IvanStarostin wow! fixed it, but still have the same error. The error on edit and delete is now changed to : Generic detail view EventUpdateView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf. which I think I'm caling with pk, but don't know why django is not detecting it.

Comment: Try to replace `<int:id>` with `<int:pk>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short**: you defined a `models` (with `s`) attribute, but it should be **`model`** (without `s`).

Well the error actually already explains the problem:

> ```
> ImproperlyConfigured at /events/1/edit/ EventUpdateView is missing a QuerySet. 
> Define EventUpdateView.model, EventUpdateView.queryset,
> or override EventUpdateView.get_queryset().)
> ```

In your `EventUpdateView` you did not specify a **`model`** attribute, you wrote `models`, and for Django that is an entirely different attribute. So you should rename it to:

```
class EventListView(ListView):
    model = EventModel
    template_name = 'event_list.html'
    queryset = EventModel.objects.order_by('start_date_time')

class EventUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = EventModel
    fields = ['event_type','start_date_time'
              ]
    template_name = 'event_update.html'

class EventDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = EventModel
    template_name = 'event_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('event_list')


class EventDetailView(DetailView):
    model = EventModel
    template_name = 'event_detail.html'
```

For the `EventListView`, that did not matter, since you also defined a `queryset` attribute, and so Django took that one, but I would update it anyway.

Furthermore in the `urls.py`, you need to specify a `pk` parameter by default:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.EventListView.as_view(), name='event_list'),
    path('<int:pk>', views.EventDetailView.as_view(), name='event_detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/edit/', views.EventUpdateView.as_view(), name='event_update'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', views.EventDeleteView.as_view(), name='event_delete'),
]
```

Finally in the template you wrote something like:

```
{% url 'event_update' event.id %}
```

But apparently there was no `event` identifier, as a result the `event.id` is the `string_if_invalid` (by default the empty string), which is not an integer (well at least not if you did not specify that), and hence it can not find a relevant URL. After some discussion, it turned out that the correct identifier was `object`, so the correct url is something like:

```
{% url 'event_update' pk=object.id %}
```

The same of course should happen with other `{% url ... %}` calls.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! actually Ivan mentioned that and I fixed it, but still I see 404 in URL/events/1/ link

Comment: @aLuViAn: yes that is because of a second problem: you named the parameter `id`, instead of `pk`. So either you update the `get_object` function, or you use `pk`.

Comment: Fixed that as well, thanks! Now my edit and delete work fine. But still I get 404 on my events/1/

Comment: @aLuViAn: are you sure there exists an `Event` with the given id?

Comment: Yes I checked the database. And my bad, the error has changed to NoReverseMatch...I think its coming from `event_detail.html` :: `<p><a href="{% url 'event_update' event.id %}">Edit</a> | <a href="{% url 'event_delete' event.id %}">Delete</a></p>` which should work fine, cos I have the exact same line in `event_list.html` and it works

Comment: @aLuViAn: ah that is in the templates, what if you use `{% url 'event_update' pk=event.id %}`, etc.?

Comment: Reverse for 'event_update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found.

Comment: @aLuViAn: it looks like your `event` does not exists, or has an empty `id`, since it says that `pk` is the empty string `''`.

Comment: ok FIXED AT LAST! I wrote : `{% url 'event_update' pk=object.id %}` and its working. dont know why it needs `object` instead of `event`. Can you elaborate this on your answer?